# Logic error when adding to a database

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, runtime-error

In my program, the user has the ability to group students together into a class. In my code, there seems to be some weird logic error; my database links a group to the students with a `StudentsGroups` table. While an input should look like this:

```
+---------------------+----------------------------------+
|      studentsgroups |                           groups |
+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+
| groupID | studentID | groupID | groupName | groupFocus |
+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+
|       1 |         1 |       1 | TestGroup |      Maths |
|       1 |         2 +---------+-----------+------------+
|       1 |         3 |
+---------+-----------+
```

My output instead looks like this:

```
+---------+-----------+
| groupID | studentID |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 |         0 |
|       2 |         0 |
|       3 |         0 |
+---------+-----------+
```

With the `groups` table being empty. I am not getting any error messages from this, so as far as I know my code runs fine, but somewhere along the way there is an issue.

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    ' We create a new instance of a Groups object to store our entered values; the group's name
    ' the group's focus and the students in this group
    Dim newGroup As New Groups
    newGroup.strGroupName = txtGroupName.Text
    newGroup.strGroupFocus = cmbGroupFocus.SelectedValue
    ' We add every student in this group list to the Groups object's student list.
    For i As Integer = 0 To lstGroupList.Items.Count - 1
        newGroup.addStudent(groupList.Item(i))
    Next
    ' Firstly, we must insert a new group into the database. This will allow us to link every
    ' student in the group to this group in our StudentsGroups table.
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connString)
        conn.Open()
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO groups(groupName, groupFocus) VALUES(@grpName, @grpFocus);"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grpName", newGroup.strGroupName)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grpFocus", newGroup.strGroupFocus)
        End Using
        conn.Close()
    End Using
    Try
        ' To get the ID of the group generated by the database, we make a temporary string to
        ' hold the ID value.
        Dim groupID As String
        Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connString)
            conn.Open()
            Using selComm As New MySqlCommand
                ' We create a SELECT query to find the new ID by using the entered group's name.
                selComm.Connection = conn
                selComm.CommandText = "SELECT groupID FROM groups WHERE groupName = @groupName;"
                selComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groupName", newGroup.strGroupName)
                selComm.Prepare()
                ' We use the ExecuteScalar method, which would return the very first entry on the
                ' first row. Since we only want one row and one result, this is better than using
                ' a DataTable and DataReader.
                groupID = selComm.ExecuteScalar()
            End Using
            conn.Close()
        End Using
        ' Now we begin to link the students to their group. We run through every student in the
        ' group list and add in their ID along with the group's ID to the table.
        For i As Integer = 0 To groupList.Count - 1
            Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connString)
                conn.Open()
                Using newCommand As New MySqlCommand
                    newCommand.Connection = conn
                    newCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO studentsgroups VALUES(@groupID, @studentID);"
                    newCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groupID", CInt(groupID))
                    ' To get the student's ID, we do the same process as above; make a new
                    ' command to get the student's ID, using ExecuteScalar.
                    Dim studentID As String
                    ' When processing a new command, we need a new connection item to 
                    Using conn2 As New MySqlConnection(connString)
                        conn2.Open()
                        Using comm2 As New MySqlCommand
                            comm2.Connection = conn2
                            comm2.CommandText = "SELECT idNumber FROM students WHERE passCode = @passcode"
                            comm2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passcode", groupList.Item(i).intIDNum)
                            comm2.Prepare()
                            studentID = comm2.ExecuteScalar()
                        End Using
                        conn2.Close()
                    End Using
                    newCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", CInt(studentID))
                    newCommand.Prepare()
                    newCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
                conn.Close()
            End Using
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.ToString())
    Finally
        MsgBox("New Group created!")
        Me.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Here is the relevant code for the submit section, would anyone know where the logic issue might be arising?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Groups table, you open the connection, format the command, and then close the connection without ever executing the command. Add the line

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

at the end of your "Using cmd..." block.

I don't see the logic error causing your GroupID to change, but I suspect the culprit is that the groupID column of the studentgroups table is set to AutoIncrement (probably because most mySQL clients default the first column as a primary key). Watch out for this when building your tables, keeping in mind that only unique values should be set as primary keys and that not every table needs a primary key.

As for why every line of your studentID column is 0, I'm having a little trouble following your code. In the lines:

```
comm2.CommandText = "SELECT idNumber FROM students WHERE passCode = @passcode"
comm2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passcode", groupList.Item(i).intIDNum)
```

you appear to be: 1) providing a student ID number 2) finding rows where the student ID number matches the passCode column and 3) getting the student ID numbers from these rows. I can't tell if this is the problem or how to fix it without knowing more about your database schema and GUI structure, but let me ask you this:

Do you need to write a query to get the student ID numbers for everyone in the group? It seems like the user has already selected the students to add and that this information is already stored in your form. Something like:

```
newCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groupID", CInt(groupID))
'Delete everything between these two lines
newCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", groupList.Item(i).intIDNum)
```

That should work if I've inferred your setup correctly. If not, please diagram the students table and explain exactly which of its columns you can access from the form.

Comment: That initial confusion is more on my part, since I worked out a lot of the code behind adding in students before my database. So when the program refers to `IDNum`, that is the same as the `passCode` column. But yes, that is what I want from my code, to add everyone in the group to the list.